# How to get enemy to appear?

Tags: python, pygame

When the game first starts both the player and the enemy appear but when the player moves the enemy disappears.

```
import pygame
import os 
import random 
from pygame.locals import * # Constants
import math
import sys
import random

pygame.init()  

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720)) #(length,height)
screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255,255,255))     # fill the background white 
White = (255,255,255)

screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

def __init__(self):

    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0,0,128), (50,560,50,25)) #(colour)(x-position,y-position,width,height)
    self.dist = 100

def draw_rect(self,x,y):    # This is my code which should make the player move
    screen.blit(background, (0, 0)) #If this isn't included then when the rectangle moves it's old positon will still be on the screen
    self.rect = self.rect.move(x*self.dist, y*self.dist); pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 128), self.rect)
    pygame.display.update()

def handle_keys(self): # code to make the character move when the arrow keys are pressed
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[K_LEFT]:
        self.draw_rect(-0.05,0)
    elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
        self.draw_rect(0.05,0)
    elif keys[K_UP]:
        self.draw_rect(0,-0.05)
    elif keys[K_DOWN]:
        self.draw_rect(0,0.05)
    elif keys[K_SPACE]:
        self.draw_rect(0.4,-0.9)
    if self.rect.right > 1280:   # These are to stop the player from going out of the boundary
        self.rect.right = 1280
    if self.rect.left < 0:
        self.rect.left = 0
    if self.rect.bottom > 720:
        self.rect.bottom = 720
    if self.rect.top < 0:
        self.rect.top = 0
```

The movement of the player works perfectly fine.

```
class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # the enemy class which works fine
def __init__(self):
    x = random.randint(50,450)
    self.rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (128,0,0), (300,x,50,25))
```

The enemy just spawns at a random place and should still appear when the player moves around. I tried to do something but it didn't work.

```
clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()

def main():  #my main loop 
    running = True
    while running:
        player.handle_keys()
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
        pygame.display.flip()   #updates the whole screen

    if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: You should try to pare this down to a [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you draw the `Rect` of the enemy only once: in the `__init__` function of `Enemy`. Also, you do a lot of drawing in different places of the `Player` class, like clearing the screen. Stop doing that.

You already subclass [`Sprite`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Sprite), so use this class as intended. Sprites have an `image` and `rect` that defines how they look like and where they are, and you add them to a [`Group`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.Group) that takes care of calling their `update` function and drawing them to the screen.

Your code should look like this:

```
import pygame
import random 
from pygame.locals import * # Constants

pygame.init()  

screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1280,720)) #(length,height)
screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
background.fill((255,255,255))     # fill the background white 

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,25))
        self.image.fill((0,0,128))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(50,560))
        self.dist = 100

    def update(self): # code to make the character move when the arrow keys are pressed

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if keys[K_LEFT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(-1,0)
        elif keys[K_RIGHT]:
            self.rect.move_ip(1,0)
        elif keys[K_UP]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,-1)
        elif keys[K_DOWN]:
            self.rect.move_ip(0,1)
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)

class Enemy(pygame.sprite.Sprite): # the enemy class which works fine
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        x = random.randint(50,450)
        self.image = pygame.Surface((50,25))
        self.image.fill((128,0,0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(topleft=(300, x))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()  # A clock to limit the frame rate.
player = Player()
enemy = Enemy()
sprites = pygame.sprite.Group(player, enemy)

def main():  #my main loop 
    running = True
    while running:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
        sprites.update()
        screen.blit(background, (0, 0))
        sprites.draw(screen)
        clock.tick(60)  # Limit the frame rate to 60 FPS.
        pygame.display.flip()   #updates the whole screen

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

Comment: thank you very much i was spending weeks to try to fix it